# Problems deserializing class after newly added member

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I have a simple "serializable" class defined as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class LayoutDetails
{       
    public bool IsRefreshEnabled { get; set; }

    public string GridSettings { get; set; }

    public List<string> GroupByPropertyNames { get; set; }
}
```

The class has been serialized using the following routine:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   var dc = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
   dc.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);

   memoryStream.Flush();

   memoryStream.Position = 0;
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
   serializedObject = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I am trying to deserialize it using the following routine:

```
   var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(serializedObject);
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes ))
   {
      var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);
      var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
      obj = serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
   }
```

This worked great; however, now, I want to add a new property to the class (`public int? Offset { get; set; }`). When I add this property to the class and try to deserialize previously serialized instances (without the property), I get an exception:

```
Error in line 1 position 148. 'EndElement' 'LayoutDetails' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WpfApplication1' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_Offset_x003E_k__BackingField'.
```

My first thought was to implement `ISerializable` and use a deserialziation ctor, so I tried something like this, but it can't find any members by name - and I've tried several combinations...

```
public LayoutDetails(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
   this.IsRefreshEnabled = (bool)info.GetValue("_x003C_IsRefreshEnabled_x003E_k__BackingField", typeof(bool));
   this.IsRefreshEnabled = (bool)info.GetValue("_x003C_IsRefreshEnabled_x003E_k_", typeof(bool));
   this.IsRefreshEnabled = (bool)info.GetValue("_x003C_IsRefreshEnabled_x003E", typeof(bool));
   this.IsRefreshEnabled = (bool)info.GetValue("x003C_IsRefreshEnabled_x003E", typeof(bool));
   this.IsRefreshEnabled = (bool)info.GetValue("IsRefreshEnabled", typeof(bool));
}
```

Using the DataContractSerializer, how can I add a new member to my class without breaking deserialization on "old" instances?

Comment: You are reading arbitrary binary data with `reader.ReadToEnd()`, that is not a very safe thing to do. I am not 100% sure about it but I think there are things you can do that will not do a round trip back in to binary data. EDIT: actually yea, this totally will not work, your serializer is using `UTF8Encoding` and your deseralizer is using `ASCIIEncoding`. I am shocked it worked so far.

Comment: I appreciate the response and good call about the encoding mismatch; I'm surprised it's working too! Nevertheless, using UTF8 in the deserializer doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backing fields for the new properties, and add attribute `OptionalField`:

```
[Serializable]
public class LayoutDetails
{       
    [OptionalField]
    private int? offset;

    public bool IsRefreshEnabled { get; set; }

    public string GridSettings { get; set; }

    public List<string> GroupByPropertyNames { get; set; }

    public int? Offset
    {
        get { return offset; }
        set { offset = value; }
    }
}
```

if you want to setup a default value, you can add a method to the class with the attribute `OnDeserializing`:

```
[OnDeserializing]
private void SetOffsetDefault(StreamingContext sc)
{
    offset = 123;
}
```